# How can I set global / environment variables to my own npm package / node module from a project?

Tags: reactjs, npm, babeljs, rollupjs

I have made my own npm package for react. We will call it @group/package 
In that package, I made exportable hooks.
As an example, I made a hook that we will call useFetchWithRefreshToken.
In that hook, I will always call the same API_URL, but the API_URL depends of my project.

I don't want to do this on all my files that need to fetch.

```js
const [load, loading] = useFetchWithRefreshToken({ url: API_URL + endpoint });
```

So, I tried to use environment variables, but as I suspected, it didn't work. The process.env values accessible from @group/package might be determined when I run npm run build / npm publish in the package, and not when I run my react app that installed it.

I can probably pass by redux to share data between my modules and my project, but I want something easier for the developer to fill in.

A .rc or .json configuration file, like babel or eslint, would be perfect.

How can I do it ?

Comment: I may not be the only one getting confused trying to read this since it seems simple but it's still unanswered. If possible, please edit to add more detail about what exactly you're trying to do.

Comment: Do you mean each react project will have its own API_URL and you want to use this API_URL of the react project in your @group/package?

Comment: @BhaveshParvatkar yes, this just an example. I would also like to do this for other specific data.

Comment: If you want to pass API_URL from react then you can define this value in env of your react project. In your package you can read it like process.env.API_URL. Basically, the repo that uses this package will declare the API_URL in its env file.

Comment: @BhaveshParvatkar I tried that and it didn't work. Maybe I'm missing something, I'll try again. Besides that, I think npm-config and .npmrc can do what I want. I've to try it too.

Comment: Is your react project using default webpack? By default react only accepts env that starts with "REACT_APP_". So your API_URL should be something like REACT_APP_API_URL.

Comment: If your react app is ejected then it will have webpack file in its root directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define your env with prefix of `REACT_APP_`. You can read more about it here: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/

ReactJS

.env

```
REACT_APP_API_URL=https://myurl.com
```

In your package you can read this env as follows

```
const [load, loading] = useFetchWithRefreshToken({ url: process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL + endpoint });
```

In case you have ejected your react app then you can find the line in webpack file where env are attached to the project and then manually add `API_URL` to support your above implementation of just using `API_URL` in your package.

Comment: That's right, over time I'd forgotten all about REACT_APP_. As the problem occurred in the context of a custom package, I didn't think to double-check something simple

Comment: Yeah, it's easy to miss when there is context switch.

Answer (score 1):

If you’re trying to read your own config files, then I would suggest using the cosmic config library. As it supports all the standard config file formats and provides a simple standard API that will read the data regardless of file format.

https://github.com/cosmiconfig/cosmiconfig

Comment: It looks interesting. Will it be read on the client side or during the build of my app like a .env file ? Maybe with the synchronous way.

Comment: It’s read at runtime, and I believe it is what Babel/eslint use to read their configs. If your running the react app server side this will work for you, which from your question is what I think your doing.